# PHP / General Math - Find next 12 day point

Tags: php, math

I am really struggling to get my head around the math here but I am going to bet it's simple and I will kick myself :)

I am writing a PHP routine that gives the user a new file every 12 days.

The starting point is a date I have stored that they started at.

I have the number of days since they started in a variable and I can divide that by 12 to calculate how many files to give them (all the filenames are stored in an array) - That's easy.

What I NOW want to do is tell them how many days until they get their next file.

So I have :

$num_days  as an integer equal to the number of days since they started.

What would be the math to calculate when the next 12 day boundary is to show them how many days until the next file please ?

Comment: Modulo!!! http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php That will "divide" two numbers and return the "leftover". Then you do 12 - that

Comment: @LordNeo it's modulo, not module, right?

Comment: @waterloomatt sorry, my englisho no bueno xD

Comment: @LordNeo moi bien

Comment: This is basic math. `$days - floor($days/12)*12` in case you don't want to use mod or just want to know how to calculate it. https://3v4l.org/7d7Ph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the mod operator (%)

[PHP MOD](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

Given X and Y, it divides X into Y and instead of returning the result, it returns the leftover.

Example:

```
8 % 2 = 0 (8/2 = 4, leftover = 0)
10 % 3 = 1 (10/3 = 3, leftover = 1)
```

So, to your specific situation

```
$days_since = $num_days % 12 //days since the "last starting period"
// for example if $num_days = 20, then $num_days % 12 = 8
$days_until = 12 - $days_since
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

PHP has lots of functions for dealing with dates and times

```
$joined = new DateTime( '2011-10-01' ); // Set this to date they joined
$now = new DateTime();  // Date now
$end = new DateTime('+13 day');  // Date in 13 days time, set to 12 if you want result to be 0 if today is file day
$interval = new DateInterval('P12D');  // Set your date interval of 12 days
$daterange = new DatePeriod($joined, $interval ,$end); // Get the date of every 12th day since they joined
$files = 0;  // Set file counter to zero
foreach($daterange as $date){     // Loop over all the dates
    $enddate =  $date;         // Sets every time so when loop ends will return the last date
    $files++;                  // Add one to the number of files for each date
}
$interval = $now->diff($enddate);  // Work out how many days between now and the next file day
echo $interval->format('%a days until your next file is available'); // Profit!
```